# Выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект

Tags: c++, массивы

Ошибка: выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект. Однако, как только я ставлю указатель, появляется другая ошибка. А именно обращения по адресу. Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char w = cin.get();
    char mem[2000];
    int ptr = 0; int lvl = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
    {
        switch (w[i])
        {
        case '+':
            mem[ptr]++;
            break;
        case '-':
            mem[ptr]--;
            break;
        case '<':
            ptr--;
            break;
        case '>':
            ptr++;
            break;
        case '.':
            cout << "\n" << mem[ptr] << "\n";
            break;
        case ',':
            mem[ptr] = cin.get();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: переменная `w` имеет тип `char`. что вы ждете от выражения `w[i]`? Опишите желаемое поведение вашей программы.

Comment: А какой тип должен быть?)

Comment: Вы хотите получить с клавиатуры _один символ_ или _целую строку_?

Comment: Я хочу получать строку

Comment: `char *xxx` - это указатель,  `char xxx[size]` - это массив. И вероятно не `mem[ptr]++;` а `mem[ptr++];`

Comment: @gggendalf, чтобы ускорить процесс, напишите пожалуйста, что должна делать программа..

Comment: `char` - это один символ, не строка. Если хотите строку, используйте `std::string`.

Comment: Практика. Интепретатор Brainfuck

Comment: Возьмите готовый, их же понаписал все кому не лень.. :) исходников полно.

Comment: string и char* даже не предлагайте. Они с cin.get() не работают

Comment: Почему не работают то? `istream &get (char *buf, streamsize num);.  
istream &get (char *buf, streamsize num, char delim);`

Comment: К - значит краткость :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;              // строка
    std::getline(std::cin, s);  // ввод строки через консольку
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        // ...
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Там где троеточие пишите логику

Comment: `cin.getline(cin, s);` - ошибка

Comment: @gggendalf, внимательнее смотрите, не `cin.getline(cin, s)` а `getline(cin, s)`

Comment: Идентификатор `getline` вовсе не определён

Comment: `std::` :) добавить наверно

Comment: `#include <string>` также нужно

Comment: Извините. Понял ошибку. Ошибка выполнения кода. Сейчас попоробую конвертировать типы

Comment: `void main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
 char buff[2000];
 char* w = gets(buff);
 char mem[2000];
 int ptr = 0; 
 int lvl = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
 {
  switch (w[i])
  {
  case '+':
   mem[ptr]++;
   break;
  case '-':
   mem[ptr]--;
   break;
  case '<':
   ptr--;
   break;
  case '>':
   ptr++;
   break;
  case '.':
   cout << "\n" << mem[ptr] << "\n";
   break;
  case ',':
   fflush(stdin);
   mem[ptr] = gets(buff)[0];
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }
 }
}` - так ещё работает без ошибок. Однако, вместо цифр выводит буквы...

Comment: В вопросе разместите, тут не читаемо, и разве есть локаль RUSSIAN?

Comment: Сейчас размещу. Локаль есть. Я думал, это все знают)

Comment: С телефона не получается. Тогда уж днём

Comment: Есть локаль `ru_RU.*` с вариациями вместо звёздочки. RUSSIAN это из области желаний :)